# 7GB of ram in use, but only chrome is open

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

So as the title says, I have 7GB or 46% of my ram being used for no particularly obvious reason. The first thing I checked is of course the Task Manager and the Resource Monitor but nothing could be found there.

[image: Task Manager]

[image]

[image: Resource Manager]

The next thing I did is search for memory leaks in drivers, using poolmon from WDK I searched for a memory leak, but nothing particularly significant was found.

[image]

I may add that this happened to me before, previous time my OS was installed after 2 weeks, so I just reinstalled the OS, but now almost a year had passed and this happened one hour ago again. I definitely cannot reinstall my OS, what can I do?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s Memory view on the Performance tab.

Comment: Could it be somehow related to whatever it is that you're using to customize the appearance of titlebars and widgets?

Comment: @DanielB provided.

Comment: @user1686 I don't think so, I had it since the very beginning and I had no problems with it. moreover, I have another PC that have this theme installed for like 2-3 years, and nothing wrong with it.

Comment: You have more than 50% of your memory free.  Chrome by itself is using more than 25% of the 7.4 GB the system is using.  What isn't shown by your Task Manager screenshots is the memory usage of the Window processes you are running.  Verify the size your page file is being handle by Windows instead of being a specific size. I see nothing usual about your memory usage.

Comment: @Ramhound Chrome uses only 1.8GB, I have 16GB of ram that is around 12%. I do have 'Automatically manage paging file size for all drives' checked. but I see that it says minimum allowed: 16MB, Recommended: 2925MB, Currently allocated: 18432MB. is that ok?

Comment: Dunno why this was closed, seeing how the other question is rather low-quality. This isn’t about the page file at all either. Not once is it mentioned in the question. // You do not have a kernel/driver memory leak. You do have integrated graphics though: Also check the GPU 0 view in Task Manager.

Comment: @DanielB check for memory in the integrated graphics? 0.3/7.9GB shared GPU memory, 0.4/7.9GB GPU memory.
And for the second GPU: 0.2/4.0GB dedicated GPU memory, 0.2/11.9GB GPU memory, 0.0/7.9 Shared GPU memory.

Comment: Does Chome on Windows show the *actual total* RAM used with the disclosure arrow closed, or is it like on Mac where you have to tot up the 40 individual tab processes you have open, in addition to the main app load? example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fytd.png

Comment: @Tetsujin In windows, it shows the total ram.

Comment: Well, it shows some added up values. These values, however, do not include shared memory at all and as such are very inaccurate with multi-process applications like modern browsers. Precise accounting of shared memory is very complicated.